# tikz: How to draw flowcharts?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I did the flowchart I have only one request it's about the word ODE15s when I write it in my code,I got it inside the dashed box ,I wanted it outside in the right.Thanks a lot for your help

[image]

```
here is the line that executes it
\node[draw, ultra thick, dashed, fit={($(in5.north)+(-4cm,0.25cm)$)($(b)+(4cm,0)$)}, ] {ODE15s};
```

Comment: Give the full source for the image (as a `standalone` document, perhaps). As it stands, it is next to impossible to suggest anything to fix the problem.

Comment: Please show a complete example, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Answer (score 1):

Without the full code it's difficult to answer…
Nonetheless, I suggest

```
…
\node (box)[draw, ultra thick, dashed, fit={($(in5.north)+(-4cm,0.25cm)$)($(b)+(4cm,0)$)}, ] {}; % remove the label and add a name
\node at (box.east) {ODE15s}; % place the label
…
```